# How to receive COM events in node-win32ole

Tags: javascript, node.js, com, atl

I have a small ATL COM object that implements one method (Method1) and fires one event (Event1) when this method was called.

I can create this COM in my nodejs script and call its method. But I am unable to receive its events.

This code works fine:

```
var win32ole = require('win32ole');

var api = new ActiveXObject("MySampleATLClass.Api");

api.Method1();
```

But this code produces errors:

```
var win32ole = require('win32ole');

var api = new ActiveXObject("MySampleATLClass.Api");

api.Event1 = function(bstr, obj){
    console.log(bstr);
};

api.Method1();
```

Error details:

> ASSERT in 00000000 module ..\src\v8variant.cc(96)
>   @node_win32ole::V8Variant::Cre ateOCVariant: !v->IsFunction()
>
> TypeError: node_win32ole::V8Variant::OLESet the second argument is not
>   valid (nu ll OCVariant)
>       at Object. (C:\NodeJs\1.js:5:12)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:906:3